# Getting this Error in Tutorial App: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: ios, arrays

PLEASE NOTE NEW EDIT!!!!

So I am trying to create an App that loads annotation from an array and shows them on a map...then when you select a location in a UITable on the left it zooms to the location on the map on the right. Below is the code for loading the annotations, setting the number of sections (to be viewed in the UITable), setting the number of rows in each section and finally writing the annotation names to the UITable so it can be used as a selector.

Problem:  The App runs but my UITable on the left (to be used to select locations) shows nothing in the Hotels section, shows the word "Empty" in the AerialView section, and shows ONE location in the Streets section with the remaining rows in the Streets section blank.

So obviously the annotation names are not being loaded into my UITable properly.  Any ideas?

```
-(void) loadOutAnnotations
{

    CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate;

    //***********HOTELS**************************

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 40.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -73.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *hotel1 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel1 setTitle:@"Hotel 1"];
    [hotel1 setSubtitle:@"This is Hotel #1"];
    [hotel1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeHotels];

    [mapView addAnnotation:hotel1];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 50.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -83.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *hotel2 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel1 setTitle:@"Hotel 2"];
    [hotel1 setSubtitle:@"This is Hotel #2"];
    [hotel1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeHotels];

    [mapView addAnnotation:hotel2];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 60.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -93.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *hotel3 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel1 setTitle:@"Hotel 3"];
    [hotel1 setSubtitle:@"This is Hotel #3"];
    [hotel1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeHotels];

    [mapView addAnnotation:hotel3];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 10.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -23.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *hotel4 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel1 setTitle:@"Hotel 4"];
    [hotel1 setSubtitle:@"This is Hotel #4"];
    [hotel1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeHotels];

    [mapView addAnnotation:hotel4];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 30.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -43.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *hotel5 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel1 setTitle:@"Hotel 5"];
    [hotel1 setSubtitle:@"This is Hotel #5"];
    [hotel1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeHotels];

    [mapView addAnnotation:hotel5];

    // *****************AERIALS*****************************

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 25.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -15.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *aerial1 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel1 setTitle:@"Aerial 1"];
    [hotel1 setSubtitle:@"This is Aerial #1"];
    [hotel1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeAerialShots];

    [mapView addAnnotation:aerial1];


    workingCoordinate.latitude = 35.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -25.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *aerial2 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel1 setTitle:@"Aerial 2"];
    [hotel1 setSubtitle:@"This is Aerial #2"];
    [hotel1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeAerialShots];

    [mapView addAnnotation:aerial2];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 45.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -35.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *aerial3 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel1 setTitle:@"Aerial 3"];    
    [hotel1 setSubtitle:@"This is Aerial #3"];
    [hotel1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeAerialShots];

    [mapView addAnnotation:aerial3];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 55.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -45.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *aerial4 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel1 setTitle:@"Aerial 4"];
    [hotel1 setSubtitle:@"This is Aerial #4"];
    [hotel1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeAerialShots];

    [mapView addAnnotation:aerial4];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 65.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -55.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *aerial5 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel1 setTitle:@"Aerial 5"];
    [hotel1 setSubtitle:@"This is Aerial #5"];
    [hotel1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeAerialShots];

    [mapView addAnnotation:aerial5];


     // *****************STREETS*****************************

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 27.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -37.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *street1 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel1 setTitle:@"Street 1"];
    [hotel1 setSubtitle:@"This is Street #1"];
    [hotel1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeStreets];

    [mapView addAnnotation:street1];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 37.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -47.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *street2 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel1 setTitle:@"Street 2"];
    [hotel1 setSubtitle:@"This is Street #2"];
    [hotel1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeStreets];

    [mapView addAnnotation:street2];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 57.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -67.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *street3 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel1 setTitle:@"Street 3"];
    [hotel1 setSubtitle:@"This is Street #3"];
    [hotel1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeStreets];

    [mapView addAnnotation:street3];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 77.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -87.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *street4 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel1 setTitle:@"Street 4"];
    [hotel1 setSubtitle:@"This is Street #4"];
    [hotel1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeStreets];

    [mapView addAnnotation:street4];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 87.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -97.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *street5 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel1 setTitle:@"Street 5"];
    [hotel1 setSubtitle:@"This is Street #5"];
    [hotel1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeStreets];

    [mapView addAnnotation:street5];
}


- (iCodeBlogAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
                   viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    iCodeBlogAnnotationView *annotationView = nil;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *myAnnotation = (iCodeBlogAnnotation *)annotation;

    if(myAnnotation.annotationType == iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeHotels)
    {
        NSString *identifier = @"Hotels";
        iCodeBlogAnnotationView *newAnnotationView = (iCodeBlogAnnotationView*)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if (newAnnotationView == nil)
        {
            newAnnotationView = [[[iCodeBlogAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:myAnnotation reuseIdentifier:identifier]autorelease];  
        }

        annotationView = newAnnotationView;
    }
    else if(myAnnotation.annotationType == iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeAerialShots)
    {
        NSString *identifier = @"AerialShots";
        iCodeBlogAnnotationView *newAnnotationView = (iCodeBlogAnnotationView*)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if (newAnnotationView == nil)
        {
            newAnnotationView = [[[iCodeBlogAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:myAnnotation reuseIdentifier:identifier]autorelease];
        }

        annotationView = newAnnotationView;
    }
    else if(myAnnotation.annotationType == iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeStreets)
    {
        NSString *identifier = @"Streets";
        iCodeBlogAnnotationView *newAnnotationView = (iCodeBlogAnnotationView*)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if (newAnnotationView == nil)
        {
            newAnnotationView = [[[iCodeBlogAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:myAnnotation reuseIdentifier:identifier]autorelease];
        }

        annotationView = newAnnotationView;
    }

    [annotationView setEnabled:YES];
    [annotationView setCanShowCallout:YES];

    return annotationView;
}

#pragma mark tableview dataSource methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
              titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeHotels)
    {
        return @"Hotels";
    }
    else if (section == iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeAerialShots)
    {
        return @"AerialShots";
    }
    else if (section == iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeStreets)
    {
        return @"Streets";
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
    }

    // here we are creating an array object BUT it is empty (it has no object in it)
    NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        for(iCodeBlogAnnotation *annotation in [mapView annotations])
        {
            if([annotation annotationType] == iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeHotels)
            {
                // here is the line where we actually add objects to the array
                [annotations addObject:annotation];
            }
        }

        if ([annotations count] > indexPath.row)
        {    
            cell.textLabel.text = [[annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Empty";
        }
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        for(iCodeBlogAnnotation *annotation in [mapView annotations])
        {
            if([annotation annotationType] == iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeAerialShots)
            {
                [annotations addObject:annotation];
            }
        }

        if ([annotations count] > indexPath.row)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [[annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Empty";
        }
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        for(iCodeBlogAnnotation *annotation in [mapView annotations])
        {
            if([annotation annotationType] == iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeStreets)
            {
                [annotations addObject:annotation];
            }
        }

        if ([annotations count] > indexPath.row)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [[annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Empty";
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: From what I understand/see, you are not "holding on" to the array. Do you have a `@property (strong,nontatomic) NSArray*` or something similar for your array?

Comment: Is this your actual code? Maybe not related to your problem, but you're not setting the title or subtitle on any of those annotations. See, you're just setting them on hotel1 like 50 times.

Comment: Oh boy....yes you are right....well that was embarrassing!!!! The only thing now is that they are not ordered. But thank you for pointing out my dumb mistake regarding the hotel 50 times issue!!

Comment: Is `mapView` an ivar of whatever class this is, declared in the `@interface`? What type is it? What does its `addAnnotation` method do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an object with `NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` it exists, but it is empty. That is, it has no objects in it. You're only adding objects to the array in this line: `[annotations addObject:annotation];`, which you may very well never get to. That is, you'll only end up adding as many objects as there are `annotation`s in `[mapView annotations]` of the correct `annotationType`.

You then blindly access a specific element of the array without checking to see if there are enough.

At the very least, you should replace this line:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];
```

With something like this:

```
if ([annotations count] > indexPath.row) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [[annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];
}
else {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Empty";
}
```

Better, you should change your implementation of

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

to make sure that you never say there are more rows in a section than there are actually annotations to put into those rows.

Comment: Okay so this definitely helped a lot...so thank you! However, when I run the app only one of my annotations is actually loaded.  Just to clarify, I have 3 sections (Hotels, AerialViews and Streets) each which should have 5 annotations loaded into those sections (so I have 15 annotations in total).  I have a -(void) loadAnnotations method which is supposed to put all 15 annotations into the array, obviously in conjunction with the actual array loading line from my original post). The Hotels section shows nothing, AerialViews show Empty for all 5, and the Streets section shows one annotation.

Comment: Please edit your original question with your code for `numberOfRowsInSection` and `loadAnnotations`

Answer (score 0):

In this like, you access an array:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];
```

and probably the annotations array is empty!

Comment: Is there a way to set the initial values of the array so that it is not empty when it is first accessed?

Comment: Also...if I try to step through the code using breakpoints it only throws the error after the SECOND if statement (the first else if statement).  So the first cell.textlabel.text.... doesnt throw any error....but the second cell.textlabel.text.... DOES throw an error

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea. Init your array in viewDidLoad (otherwise you do it every time there is a cell).  Load the array with values in viewDidLoad before the table does it's thing.  If you can't add values, then put an if statement making sure that if the array size is zero then don't do any of the code that will access an array